# How to use Join query between CTE and two tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I want to use a join query in CTE between two tables `EmployeeDetails` and `MachineAttendance`, but I'm confused - how will it be used?

```
;With CTE As
(
    select ed.EmpName 
    from EmployeeDetails ed
)
,cte1; AS
(
    select 
        ma.EmpID, cast(MA.Datetime as Date) as [Date], 
        case when MA.INOUT = 1 then DateTime end as INOUT_INTIME,
        case when MA.INOUT = 2 then DateTime end as INOUT_OUTTIME
    from 
        MachineAttendance MA
), cte2 as
(
    select  
        EmpID, [Date], 
        MAX(INOUT_INTIME) AS INTIME, 
        MAX(INOUT_OUTTIME) AS OUTTIME,
        DATEDIFF(Hour, MAX(INOUT_INTIME), MAX(INOUT_OUTTIME)) as [Hours]
    from 
        CTE1
    group by 
        EmpID, [Date]
)
select 
    EmpID, [Date], INTIME, OUTTIME, [Hours],
    case
       when [Hours] >= 8 then 1
       when [Hours] = 0 then 0
       when [Hours] >= 6 then 0.5 
    end as [Day],
    case 
       when [Hours] > 8 then [Hours] - 8 
       else 0 
    end as OT,
    case 
       when [Hours] >= 8 
          then ([Hours] - 8) * 100 else 0 
    end as OTAMount,
    Convert(varchar(10), Date, 120) as [Date],
    Convert(varchar(10), INTIME, 108) as [Time],
    Case 
       When Convert(Time, INTIME, 108) > '09:10' 
          Then 1 else 0 
    end as Late
from
    cte2
inner join 
    cte On cte.EmpID = cte2.EmpID`
```

Comment: You had all those unnecessary backticks `  that probably caused errors - I removed those. Also: after the `cte1`, there's a semicolon which shouldn't be there - remove that, too! Then I believe the code should work

Comment: @marc_s  my issue now resolve ,,,i did not add col in cte2  ' select cte.EmpName, cte2.EmpID,cte.OTEntitled,  cte2.INTIME,  cte2.OUTTIME,  cte2.[Hours]'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You typed mixed syntax mysql and sql server and some extra comma was ther i think below will work

```
    ;With CTE As
    (
    select ed.EmpName from EmployeeDetails ed
    )    
    ,cte1 AS
    (
    SELECT ma.EmpID, CAST(MA.Datetime as Date) AS [Date], 
    CASE WHEN MA.INOUT = 1 THEN DateTime END AS INOUT_INTIME,
    CASE WHEN MA.INOUT = 2 THEN DateTime END AS INOUT_OUTTIME
    From 
     MachineAttendance MA
    ), 
   cte2 
    as
    (
    select EmpID, [Date], MAX(INOUT_INTIME) AS INTIME, 
                          MAX(INOUT_OUTTIME) AS OUTTIME
    , DATEDIFF(Hour, MAX(INOUT_INTIME), MAX(INOUT_OUTTIME)) as [Hours]
    FROM CTE1
    GROUP BY EmpID, [Date]
    )
    select EmpID, [Date], INTIME, OUTTIME, [Hours]
    , CASE WHEN [Hours] >= 8 THEN 1
    WHEN [Hours] = 0 THEN 0
    WHEN [Hours] >= 6 THEN 0.5 END AS [Day],
    CASE WHEN [Hours] > 8 then [Hours] - 8 else 0 End as OT,
    CASE WHEN [Hours] >= 8 
    then ([Hours] - 8) * 100 else 0 END AS OTAMount,
    Convert(varchar(10),Date,120) as [Date],
    Convert(varchar(10),INTIME,108) as [Time],
    Case When Convert(Time,INTIME,108) > '09:10' Then 1 else 0 end as Late
    from cte2
    INNER Join cte On cte.EmpID=cte2.EmpID
```

Comment: i am getting this error 'Msg 209, Level 16, State 1, Line 22
Ambiguous column name 'EmpID'.'

Comment: use tablename.column name in selection

Comment: The multi-part identifier "MachineAttendance.EmpID" could not be bound.